# Simplify HTML table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I wanted to create table to looks more simple using a PHP array and I need some help using Javascript.
Originally I wanted to create table like the first one, then I had problem due to limitation from provider of the PHP array.

```html
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}


</style>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="3">Scope/Coverage</td>
   <td colspan="5">Economically Active</td>
   <td rowspan="3">Percentage of Working to Economically Active</td>
   <td colspan="4">Not Economically Active</td>
   <td rowspan="3">Total</td>
   <td rowspan="3">Percentage of Economically Active to Working Age Population</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="2">Working</td>
   <td colspan="3">Unemployment</td>
   <td rowspan="2">Total of Economically Active</td>
   <td rowspan="2">Attending School</td>
   <td rowspan="2">Housekeeping</td>
   <td rowspan="2">Total of Not Economically Active</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Ever Worked</td>
   <td>Never Worked</td>
   <td>Total</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

Due to limitation from developer, I was given a specific PHP array and printed like this:

```html
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}


</style>
<table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <td rowspan="3">Scope/Coverage</td>
        <td>Economically Active</td><td>Economically Active</td><td>Economically Active</td><td>Economically Active</td><td>Economically Active</td><td></td><td>Not Economically Active</td><td>Not Economically Active</td><td>Not Economically Active</td><td>Not Economically Active</td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td>Unemployment</td><td>Unemployment</td><td>Unemployment</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>Working</td><td>Ever Worked</td><td>Never Worked</td><td>Total</td><td>Total of Economically Active</td><td>Percentage of Working to Economically Active</td><td>Attending School</td><td>Housekeeping</td><td>Others</td><td>Total of Not Economically Active</td><td>Total</td><td>Percentage of Economically Active to Working Age Population</td></tr><tr>    </tr>
   </thead>
  </table>
```

It would be a great if you help me solved this problem

Comment: why are you not using ajax to get data and append into dom with html table

Comment: You'd want to show the data array you mentioned in your post. When you do you'll probably get three or four answers almost right away as the alg will be very straightforward.